# Obter X e Y de <g> com ID mesmo quando der zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, offset

Tenho um mapa do Brasil com vários `<g>` do svg. Cada elemento desse é um municipio. Preciso pegar o X e Y desse elemento em relação a div que o svg está.
O problema maior é porque eu tenho um zoom, que ao clicar por exemplo em "Mais Zoom" ele da zoom alterando a matrix do `<g>`, sendo assim o mapa do Brasil fica mais perto da tela, mas o X e o Y dele se mantém o mesmo em relação a div. Então se tiver muito longe ou muito perto o zoom, não adianta, pois o X e Y se mantém fixo.

Estou pegando o X e o Y com o código:

```
var path      = document.getElementById(municipio).getBoundingClientRect();
var svggerado = document.getElementById('svggeradodiv').getBoundingClientRect();

var calculaX  = Math.round(path.left - (svggerado.left + 110));
var calculaY  = Math.round(path.top);
```

Comment: Mostre um exemplo. Você tem um JSFiddle disso? Vale a pena investir algumas horas e entender bem o funcionamento de `matrix()` e dos sistemas de coordenadas do SVG (que podem ser alterados para cada elemento). Aqui tem um bom [tutorial que descreve em detalhes a matemática][http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/]. Você está usando D3? É bem mais fácil manipular zooms e mapas usando SVG através de um framework como [D3.js][d3js.org]. Vale a pena dar uma olhada.